Cycloheptatrienyl anion is antiaromatic or non-aromatic?
Cycloheptatrienyl anion antiaromatic or non-aromatic?
At first, it seems like it is antiaromatic due to the presence of $8 \pi$ electrons, but some sources say it is non-aromatic as $sp^3$ carbon destroys its planarity and the compound become non-planar and thus non-aromatic.
What is it actually?

Do you mean the cycloheptatrienyl anion? Cycloheptadienyl has two double bonds and a lone pair, so it could not easily have 8 electrons in $\pi$-symmetry orbitals

@NicolauSakerNeto thanks, i was indeed talking about the cycloheptatrienyl anion.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29428/is-cyclopentadiene-or-cycloheptatriene-more-acidic

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44401/why-is-cyclopentadiene-anion-is-aromatic-but-cycloheptatrienyl-anion-is-not

I want to preface this by saying that the geometry determines the hybridization, not the other way around.
That said, the molecule is not anti-aromatic. For that, the molecule would need to be cyclic, have a conjugated π-electron system, be planar, and have 4n π-electrons within the system. The cycloheptadienyl anion does not meet the 4n π-electron requirement (it has 6 π-electrons, four in the double bonds and two more from the lone pair), and neither does it meet the conjugation or planarity requirements.
In this case, the lone pair does not contribute to making the molecule planar like it would with something like the cyclopentadienyl anion. The carbon with the negative charge on it will be somewhere between $\text{sp}^3$ and $\text{sp}^2$ hybridized. What carbon the anion is on is inconsequential here; a pure $\text{sp}^2$ hybrid is not possible because of the significant ring strain that would develop with this geometry. Regardless, there are always two other tetrahedral carbons (in their $\text{sp}^3$ hybridized geometry) which make the molecule non-planar. You would classify this molecule as non-aromatic.

Cycloheptatrienyl is the more common example, and perhaps what you meant in your question considering you mention 8 π-electrons. Consider (in the photo below) the carbanion; if this molecule was planar, it would be anti-aromatic (4n π-electrons, conjugated, and cyclic) and consequently incredibly unstable. The 'why' behind the instability of this anti-aromaticity (for pretty much all molecules) has to do with the molecular orbitals (which I encourage you to investigate more about). For a shortcut, you can try drawing the Frost circle for the cycloheptatrienyl anion and find the presence two unpaired electrons both in the antibonding MOs! Not very stable.
As pointed out by Mithoron, practically the molecule will bend out of planarity to create a tetrahedral carbon (with the anion on it) to avoid the anti-aromatic destabilization, facilitated by the large enough ring system, making it non-aromatic too.


thanks for the answer, i was indeed talking about the cycloheptatrienyl anion.  when i searched the google for an answer it was said that cycloheptatrienyl anion is antiaromatic if it remains planar. Then what is the condition of being planar. When will the compound be planar and when non planar?

Anything rotationally limiting (double or triple bonds, electronic interactions, or delocalizing electrons for example) will result in planar structures.

Except cycloheptatrienyl is obviously not any more planar than cyclooctatetraen.

I don't understand what you mean, @Mithoron: the [cycloheptatrienyl] anion is planar, which this post is about. The regular cycloheptatriene molecule is not planar. Cyclooctatetraene is non-aromatic because it adopts the boat configuration. Where is the comparison?

Cycloheptatrienyl anion does same thing as cyclooctatetraene.

Ah, it bends out of planarity too? I assume it would be happier being non-planar to avoid its anti-aromaticity. Okay. I'll correct my answer to reflect that. Sorry!

Antiaromaticity indicates that the given atomic configuration corresponds to a maximum on the energy surface, assuming no further complications such as fused rings or triple bonds. Thus in the absence of such complications it will always distort; there are no simple anti aromatic annulenes or related ions. Really it's just another form of the Jahn-Teller distortion.

@IanBush a singlet state of a Hückel-antiaromatic ring will always distort, but a triplet state may survive with full symmetry. My answer cites calculations indicating that an isolated cycloheptatrienyl anion does the latter.

It's a little bit of both, really. From Salikov et al.[1]:

The ground state of cycloheptatrienyl anion in the gas phase is triplet, planar and Baird-aromatic. In DMSO, it assumes a singlet distorted allylic form with a paratropic ring current. The other derivatives in both phases assume either allylic or diallylic conformations depending on the substituent pattern.

Decoding things:
The term "Baird-aromatic" for the gas-phase structure refers to the triplet state often called "antiaromatic". This concept is explained here in reference to the cyclopropenyl system. The triplet ring state is actually more resonance-stabilized than a corresponding acyclic structure with the same triplet spin state, but significantly less stablized than a Hückel-aromatic ring following the usual $4n+2$ rule would be.
The "allylic/diallylic" structure of the substituted rings, and the unsubstituted ring in DMSO solvent, actually break the ring conjugation along certain bonds, producing isolated double bonds and allylic groups. These structures would then properly be called nonaromatic.
The calculations cited above are theoretical, but the existence of  cycloheptatrienyl anion has some experimental evidence[2]. A solution of cycloheptatriene in basic liquid ammonia ("basic" here meaning they added $\ce{KNH2}$) will dimerize the hydrocarbon to a mixture of tricyclic products; the above reference reports evidence for the cycloheptatrienyl anion as an intermediate in this reaction.
References

Salikov RF, Belyy AY, Ilyushchenko MK Platonov DN, Sokolova AD, Tomilov YV. "Antiaromaticity of Cycloheptatrienyl Anions: Structure, Acidity, and Magnetic Properties". Chemistry. 2024 Jul 19; 30(41):e202401041. doi: 10.1002/chem.202401041. Epub 2024 Jul 5. PMID: 38785416.

Stuart W. Staley, Arnold W. Orvedal. "Mechanism of the bass[sic]-promoted cyclodimerization of cycloheptatriene".
J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1974, 96, 5, 1618–1620. doi: 10.1021/ja00812a070.


